# Show that $(X_{\sigma\wedge n },\mathcal{F}_n)_n $ is martingal and $(\|X_{\sigma\wedge n }\|,\mathcal{F}_n)_n $ is a sub-martingal.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $(E,\|.\|) $ be a Banach space.

$$
L_{E}^{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})=\{f:\Omega \rightarrow E : \int_{\Omega} \|f\| d\mathbb{P} < \infty\}
$$
Let  $(X_n)_n \subset L_{E}^{1}( \Omega)$  be a sequence of random variable and $\left(\mathcal{F}_n\right)_{n\ge 1} $ is an increasing sequence of sub- $\sigma$ -algebra of $\mathcal{F}$ , such as : $(X_n,\mathcal{F}_n)_n $ be a martingal.
Let $ t\geq 0$ we put:
$$
\sigma : \Omega \to \mathbb {N}\cup \{\infty\}
$$
Such as :
$$
    \sigma(\omega)= 
\begin{cases}
      n  & \text{if } \|X_i(\omega)\|<t ~for ~i=1,...,n-1~and ~\|X_i (\omega)\|\geq t\\
    +\infty   &  \|X_i(\omega)\|<t~\forall i
\end{cases}
$$
$\sigma$ is a stopping time with respect to $(\mathcal{F}_n)_n$.

Show that $(X_{\sigma\wedge n },\mathcal{F}_n)_n $ is martingal and $(\|X_{\sigma\wedge n }\|,\mathcal{F}_n)_n $ is a sub-martingal.

Comment: Show that $(X_{\sigma\wedge n },\mathcal{F}_n)_n $ is martingale ... Can you do the  scalar-valued case?  If so, in the vector-valued case consider $f(X_n)$ for all $f \in E^*$.

Comment: ".... If so, in the vector-valued case consider $f(X_n)$ for all $f\in E^∗$." , Why ?

Comment: To be clear, the norm $\|\cdot\|$ is the $L^1$ norm, i.e. $\|f-g\| = \int_\Omega |f-g|\ \mathsf d\mathbb P$?

Comment: Well, he writes $(E,\|\cdot\|)$, but then he writes $|X_i(\omega)|$ where presumably $|\cdot|$ is that same norm on the Banach space.  @Math1000: **No**, I think $\|X_{\sigma \wedge n}\|$ is the random variable $\|X_{\sigma \wedge n}(\omega)\|$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is the norm in the Banach space $E$.

Comment: In his definition of $L^1_E$ he uses the norm $\|\cdot\|$. That suggests to me that the norm on the Banach space is indeed the $L^1$ norm.